# How do I count the number of comments for each of my posts (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables that matter here. One table is called POSTS and contains both posts and replies (replies are treated exactly the same as posts but they have POSTS.id of referred post inside POSTS.reply).

My second table is called social and contains POST.id as a foreign key alongside the views and likes + the user that likes and views it.

I use this SELECT to get all my posts data with the title, content... likes, and views:

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.username, posts.time, cat.cat_name, 
posts.title, posts.content, posts.reply,
posts.user_file, posts.audio,
social.views, social.likes
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN user on posts.user_id = user.id 
LEFT JOIN cat ON posts.cat_id = cat.id
LEFT JOIN social ON posts.id = social.post_id
WHERE social.likes IN (SELECT social.likes FROM social 
WHERE social.id IN (SELECT MAX(social.id) 
FROM social GROUP BY post_id))
GROUP BY social.post_id
HAVING posts.reply = 0
```

I can't figure out how to have a row which contains the number of REPLIES responding to the specific post (1 row should contain all the data for me to disply on the page).

**I can't figure out how to have a row that contains the number of REPLIES responding to the specific post** (1 row should contain all the data for me to display on the page).

Normally I get the comments like this but I don't know how to merge these:)

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.reply != 0
```

The structure looks like this:

[image]

From the query I expect to recive:

```
    "username"  "time"  "cat_name"  "title" "content"   "reply" "user_file" "audio" "views" "likes" "id"    "username"  
   "xxx_user_xxx" "YYYY-MM-DD"  "topic" "Title."    "NSJNASNJSAN?"  "reply: 1/not reply: 0" "/user_uploads/xxx.yyy" "audio or video"    "number of views"   "number oflikes"
```

Now I want to get an additional column REPLIES (that does this SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posts.reply != 0) and gets the number of replies for each posts.

Comment: Please provide table structure with few sample data and expected output.

Comment: Maybe this will clear it up a bit.

Comment: If two tables matter, why does the sample code refer to five or six tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understand you need the replies for each post.
I created a table with post_id, user_id and reply_id and inserted some dummy values.

```
create table t1
(id int, user_id int,reply int);
 
 insert into t1 values(100,1,0);
 insert into t1 values(101,2,100);
 insert into t1 values(102,1,100);
 insert into t1 values(103,2,0);
 insert into t1 values(104,3,103);
```

And then a simple self join will yield you the replies to each post with below code.

```
select a.id,a.user_id,count(b.reply)
from t1 a
left join t1 b
on a.id=b.reply
group by 1,2;
```

Comment: This is perfect! Just to clarify:  I ended up including it like this under the other JOINS in the original select `...  
LEFT JOIN
(
 SELECT a.id, count(b.reply) AS b
 FROM posts a
 LEFT JOIN posts b
 on a.id = b.reply
 GROUP BY a.id, a.user_id
 HAVING b != 0
) t2
ON t1.id = t2.id    
...` (HAVING b!= 0 is because those are normal posts not replies).